# Function App not connecting to private Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm

Having deployed Function App and Cognitive Search components into Azure (via terraform) we are running into issues of the Function App not being able to connect to Cognitive Search (unless it's public).

Configuration of Cognitive Search:

- Public network access disabled
- Private endpoint added
- Is sitting on a subnet within the virtual network
- Private DNS Zone added for "privatelink.search.windows.net"
- Private DNS Zone is connected to the virtual network

It is accessible from a Container Instance that sits on the same vnet, which makes me believe it's a configuration in the Function App.

Configuration of Function App:

- dotnet function app
- Subnet created with a delegation for Microsoft.Web/serverFarms
- VNet integration is switched on against the function app subnet
- Is linked to an Elastic Premium service plan
- Service endpoint to Microsoft.Storage has been added to the function app subnet

The Function App is otherwise accessible via a Health endpoint and when the Cognitive Search component is marked as publicly accessible, the search function runs correctly.

If I set the "vnet_route_all_enabled" flag in the terraform or set the "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL" value in the app_settings block of the azurerm_windows_function_app resource to true/"1", then all connections to the Function App return a 500 error (even to the HealthCheck endpoint).

The exception generated by the Azure.Search.Documents.SearchClient class when calling SearchAsync is that the target failed to respond. I'm suspecting that the function app is NOT using the vnet to route the connection and is attempting to use the public one.

Is there anything obvious that I've missed?